# Is there a great way to grab the results from several cluster outputs in to one in the form of a dataframe? Any Suggestions?

Tags: r, output, cluster-computing

I am completing a cluster analysis on a data set and slice and dicing it in to various parts using a variety of methods, all with the goal to maximize the outcome of using kmeans to segment a large set of data.   So there are 15 separate kmeans objects as results that it would be very helpful to be able to turn these in to a table to view all at once, including the title to reference the model, and key statistics about each model.   Any advice?   Any example of the results when you just print the results to the output section of R Studio is below.  I've searched for packages etc and have not had any luck.  Thanks for any help you can provide!!!

```
 K-means clustering with 5 clusters of sizes 11356, 4621, 3380, 7455, 4381

Cluster means:
  PRCT_DIFF_LOCK_ON PRCT_FRONT_PTO_ON PRCT_REAR_PTO_ON PRCT_MFWD_ON
1       0.045629787      0.0006149385       0.05848930   0.80521712
2       0.006848544      0.0036244639       0.15807745   0.06906081
3       0.390860459      0.0004615964       0.07576421   0.79353567
4       0.040412934      0.0048262841       0.11052730   0.48966547
5       0.053424999      0.0149324570       0.45581038   0.64261907
Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
    [1] 665.8571 568.6334 264.2810 554.8512 457.3876
     (between_SS / total_SS =  55.5 %)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `kmeans` is a `list`.  If we want to extract the `Cluster means`, use

```
k2$centers
    Murder    Assault   UrbanPop       Rape
1  1.004934  1.0138274  0.1975853  0.8469650
2 -0.669956 -0.6758849 -0.1317235 -0.5646433
```

---

`broom` package can summarise the output in a data.frame/tibble

```
library(broom)
> tidy(k2)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  Murder Assault UrbanPop   Rape  size withinss cluster
   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <fct>  
1  1.00    1.01     0.198  0.847    20     46.7 1      
2 -0.670  -0.676   -0.132 -0.565    30     56.1 2      
> glance(k2)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  totss tot.withinss betweenss  iter
  <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1   196         103.      93.1     1
```

-reproducible example

```
library(cluster)  
df <- USArrests
df <- na.omit(df)
df <- scale(df)
k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
```

Comment: Thank you!   I have several different list names tied to several different data sets that created the kmeans output.   So in your example there would be k2, p6, df1, etc together with separate data sets that are subsets of the same main data frame.   Is it possible to complete a summary of all that?

Comment: You can use `bind_rows(tidy(k2), glance(k2))`  depends on how you wanted and what all info should be included